# Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) with a numeric variable

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to impute a large data set with the `Amelia` package. When calling the `amelia` function I get this error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Because I do not have factor variables with 1 level I started removing variable for variable to see which variable causes this problem. I tracked it down to this numerical variable, amelia works when I remove this single variable from the data set:

```
> str(train$ABC)
 num [1:1600] 5.19 5.38 5.59 5.26 5.12 ...
```

however there is nothing strange with this variable:

```
> summary(train$ABC)
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
4.533   5.166   5.328   5.434   5.557   7.914     610 

> summary(na.omit(train))

        ABC              ...
   Min.   :4.533   
   1st Qu.:5.196  
   Median :5.384   
   Mean   :5.512  
   3rd Qu.:5.668   
   Max.   :7.520

> var(train$ABC,na.rm=T)
     [1] 0.1969697

> aa <- na.omit(train)
> var(aa$ABC)
 [1] 0.2500173
```

I'm sorry I cannot provide the full data set as this is a medical study I'm working on and I could not make up a trivial example.

What else could cause this error? Where should I start looking?
thanks.

Comment: Did you work this out? I'm having the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today and it was due to the many missing values.

Basically, even if you original data frame `df` contains only factors with >=2 levels, when you use `df` inside `lm()` the incomplete observations are dropped (at least the ones concerning your variables of interest). Thus it is not `df` you need to check for factors with <2 levels, but `df[complete.cases(df),]`. In that data frame, at least one factor variable will be left with only 1 level (check `levels(droplevels(x))`).

I guess you guys already solved it, but maybe it will help somebody else in the future!